# Alternatives to mysqli_num_fields not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried `mysqli_fetch_field`, `mysqli_fetch_fields` and `mysqli_fetch_field_direct`, but none of them seem to be working. Here's my code:

```
// Fetch Record from Database

$output = "";
$table = "excel"; // Enter Your Table Name 
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from $table");
$columns_total = mysqli_num_fields($sql);

// Get The Field Name

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$heading = mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
$output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";
```

The error of running this code is:

> mysql_field_name() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Trying mysqli_fetch_field_direct gives this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in

Comment: check ur `$connection`

Answer (score 0):

Use     [mysqli_fetch_field_direct](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php) instead of [mysql_field_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php) in your code... See the example below

```
// Fetch Record from Database

$output = "";
$table = "excel"; // Enter Your Table Name 
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from $table");
$columns_total = mysqli_num_fields($sql);

// Get The Field Name

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
 $heading = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($sql, $i);
 $output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";
```

Comment: I did try using mysqli_fetch_field_direct, but it gave me this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_field_direct() 

Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Ooops, that error was when I missed "i" in mysql, but when I wrote it proper mysqli, it gave me this error:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in